# Question on tokenUri

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, opensea, pinata

suppose I have 10 images in a folder, I got the CID of that folder by uploading it on pinata, what is the fastest way to get tokenURI for each images?

Answer (score 1):

The base token URI would be the same for all ten the only change you will see is a change in the name of the file after the CID.

For example, if I have uploaded the photos like 1.json, 2.json, 3.json, etc.

The URI will look like this:

```
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmYLwrqMmzC3k4eZu7qJ4MZJ4SNYMgqbRJFLkyiPtUBZUP/1.json
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmYLwrqMmzC3k4eZu7qJ4MZJ4SNYMgqbRJFLkyiPtUBZUP/2.json
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmYLwrqMmzC3k4eZu7qJ4MZJ4SNYMgqbRJFLkyiPtUBZUP/3.json
```

This is a folder for example.
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmYLwrqMmzC3k4eZu7qJ4MZJ4SNYMgqbRJFLkyiPtUBZUP/